# Ford Mondeo 2014 Mk4 Headlamp fuse/relay location

Tags: ford, fuse, mondeo

Last night I noticed by headlamps weren't working ... I rotated the knob and only the day running lights remained on. I toggled full beam and that worked... so it's just normal beam and whilst I was turning the dial back and forth, a message appeared on the cluster stating "low beam bulb fault".

Having both sides go at the same time feels not normal so I suspect it's potentially a fuse or relay. I've had a look at the manual and the fuse diagram but can't find anything for headlamps... can someone help me locate it?

thanks

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

It's not unheard of to have both headlamps fail within a short time of each other.  After all, they're running for the same amount of time.  I'd probably just try replacing the bulbs -- worst case, it does nothing and you have two spare bulbs for when the lights do finally fail.

---

There are three fuse boxes for your car: one under the hood/bonnet on the driver's side, one under the glove box, and one in the trunk on the driver's side.

[image: fuse box locations]

To get at the engine compartment one, you'll have to press on the side and top of this box, then lift the cover off.

[image: engine fuse box]

It'll look roughly like this:

[image: opened engine fuse box]

The fuses we're interested in are:

- F39: 15 amp; Adaptive Front Lighting System (AFS)
- F40: 5 amp; Headlamp leveling / AFS module

To my knowledge, those are all the fuses relating to the headlights.  I could be wrong there though. [More information is available here](http://knigaproavto.ru/shemy/en/ford/mondeo/478-2007-2014-ford-mondeo-mk4-fuse-box-diagram.html).

Comment: Thanks for the info on the fuses... I had a look and they were fine. Still surprised that there isn't an obvious single fuse for the headlights!
As it is, turned out to be both lights going out and a quick replacement worked!